# Ignore active filter states when getting items from ListModel

Tags: model, filter

When trying to get all items from my list model inside a plugin, I use this:

```
$objects = $app->bootComponent('com_foo')->getMVCFactory()->createModel('Objects', 'MyModel', ['ignore_request' => true])->getItems();
```

Works fine, but if there is a filter active in the list view, the state is being also used inside the above query. How can all active backend list view filter states be ignored when using such a query?

Comment: `ignore_request` configuration parameter should be handling this. If that doesn't work, you'll have to debug your model.